# Slick Carousel displaying to the left then disapearing

Tags: carousel, slick.js

I use the slick carousel on a regular basis and today I am experiencing an issue thats making me feel like I'm going insane.

When I apply the .slick() method to the parent element all the slides appear to the left of the page, the page extends horizontially by a lot and then when you attempt to slide it just jumps all over the place.

I have created a  codepen to show the issue I'm having which you can see here https://codepen.io/harrietmcmahon/pen/pLWMbX?editors=1111

I've got

```
  <div class="js--sc">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

Applying .slick to js--sc

I've tried this with additional settings and without, I even tried just copying another codepen where it works, and it broke on that too!

Would really appreciate if someone could point out what I'm missing, or if anyone has experienced this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to include the Slick CSS

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css`
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css`

Comment: Thanks so much, I included it in the build originally it must not have been pulling through. What a waste of an afternoon that was!

Comment: It stumped me for a bit too. I honestly thought it was a bug with the new slick version